# I am looking for a data set of conversation between real state agent & prospect to train model to evaluate customer care employee performance

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, large-datasets

By using the data set I will train model for analyzing customer care's representatives performance and ensure customer satisfaction. The data set should be in English.

Comment: Audio data? Or chat, or email, or any ot them?